# Writing a function in VBA to return a triangular random number

Tags: vba, excel, function, random

I am trying to write a series of VBA functions for excel that would return random number types to call in subroutines. I am getting a similar error once I go into the more complicated formulas. For example: the asymmetric triangular random variable.

Here is the function:

```
Function AsymetricTriangleInVBA (min As Double, mode As Double, max As Double) As Double
  Application.Volatile
  Randomize
  Dim Temp As Variant
  Temp = Rnd
  AsymetricTriangleInVBA = WorksheetFunction.if(Temp < ((mode - min) / (max - min)), min + (max - min) * WorksheetFunction.sqrt(((mode - min) / (max - min)) * Temp), min + (max - min) * (1 - WorksheetFunction.sqrt((1 - ((mode - min) / (max - min))) * (1 - Temp))))
End Function

'my test sub

Sub test()
    MsgBox AsymetricTriangleInVBA(5, 10, 15)
End Sub
```

The consistent error I am receiving is:

> Run time error '438':
>   Object does not support this property or method

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: There is no WorksheetFunction.IF  You will need to use the vba form of if.

Comment: try replacing `WorksheetFunction.if` with `IIF`

Comment: Slai- iif didn't work, same error

Comment: Scott-thanks for the hint, i'll try it that way

Comment: oh, you can also replace `WorksheetFunction.sqrt` with `Sqr`. The lowercase after the dot is usually a sign that the function does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't usually use `WorksheetFunction` whenever a equivalent is available in VBA itself...in this case `SQR`

2 ways which i thought could make it work..

1)

```
Function AsymetricTriangleInVBA(min As Double, mode As Double, max As Double) As Double
  Application.Volatile
  Dim intCondition As Integer
  Randomize
  Dim Temp As Variant
  Temp = Rnd
  intCondition = CInt(Temp < ((mode - min) / (max - min))) * -1
  AsymetricTriangleInVBA = intCondition * (min + (max - min) * Sqr(((mode - min) / (max - min)) * Temp)) + (1 - intCondition) * (min + (max - min) * (1 - Sqr((1 - ((mode - min) / (max - min))) * (1 - Temp))))
End Function
```

2)

```
Function AsymetricTriangleInVBA(min As Double, mode As Double, max As Double) As Double
  Application.Volatile

  Randomize
  Dim Temp As Variant
  Temp = Rnd

    If Temp < ((mode - min) / (max - min)) Then
        AsymetricTriangleInVBA = (min + (max - min) * Sqr(((mode - min) / (max - min)) * Temp))
    Else
        AsymetricTriangleInVBA = (min + (max - min) * (1 - Sqr((1 - ((mode - min) / (max - min))) * (1 - Temp))))
    End If


End Function
```